# Duplicated foreach image on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have slight problem displaying images in slider, I am using `<li>` and foreach (thumbail from featured image). Images are shown correctly, the way i want them, but they are, for one or another reason duplicated.

Here's the screenshot: 
[image]

And here's code I've been using:

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'    => 'client'
    );
    $home_clients = get_posts($args);
    if($home_clients): 
?>
<div class="client">
    <h5>clients</h5>
    <div class="show-client">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <?php foreach($home_clients as $post): setup_postdata($post); 
            $client_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'client_link', true);
            ?>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="<?php echo $client_link; ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'client-thumb'); ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's the HTML output:

```
<h5>clients</h5>
    <div class="show-client">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#test1"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/redcrossx1-50x50.png" class="attachment-client-thumb wp-post-image" alt="test" /></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#test2"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Screen-Shot-2014-08-20-at-3.14.28-PM-50x50.png" class="attachment-client-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Screen Shot 2014-08-20 at 3.14.28 PM" /></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#test3"><img width="50" height="33" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC_9456.jpg" class="attachment-client-thumb wp-post-image" alt="DSC_9456" /></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The more i look, the more confused I am. I guess it's something with CSS actually, but not sure why it takes too damn much to load images...

Here's my css code:

```
.bot-footer .sss-client h5 {
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 43px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.bot-footer .sss-client .show-client {
    float: left;
    max-width: 877px;
    margin: 14px 0;
    height: 22px;
}
.show-client ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
.show-client ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.show-client ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
.show-client ul li a:hover {
    color: #0f6cb6;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper {
    max-width: 877px !important;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    max-width: 740px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    background: url(images/icon-arrow-footer-l.png) no-repeat center;
    left: -30px;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    background: url(images/icon-arrow-footer-r.png) no-repeat center;
    right: -10px;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: center center;
}
.show-client .bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the table that having same thumbnail name repeated? coz your code seems ok

Comment: @Wazan I have updated op with full part... Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: What's the HTML output?

Comment: Check whether print both inside the <li> ?

Comment: @JoranDenHouting i updated op with HTML output, don't mind numerous li elements, they are being pulled as i have posts without images. Showing only images though.

Comment: Your output also shows the images only once... Live demo link?

Comment: @JoranDenHouting I'll rather not share the live link (can't really do for private reason) but if there's some way to get in touch please let me know? I will share privately.

Comment: Not sure why, but it also takes some (more than normal) time to load these images...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will be to use Firebug (or other DOM viewing tool) to inspect the DOM to see how the 2nd image is appearing. Once you see the actual DOM html (instead of page source) you will be OK.

If you in fact have 2 DOM elements, odds are you have JavaScript that is conflicting with what you are really wanting to accomplish.